# Photosynthesizing (American English vs British English)

Tags: british-english, orthography

For British English, does the word photosynthesizing include a 'z'? Or is this the American English spelling?

Comment: What has your research found?

Answer (score 1):

[From Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photosynthesis#medicalDictionary):

> photosynthesize also British photosynthesise intransitive verb

[In general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling), words ending in "-ize" are American-English, and words ending in "-ise" are British-English (with a few exceptions)

Comment: Thanks. So the correct British-English spelling is "photosynthesising"?

Comment: @JulianAngussmith Yes. However, if you're writing for a journal or something, be careful that they aren't using the Oxford Standard, which does use the "-ize" ending. But otherwise, generally, the use of "-ise" is standard for British-English

Comment: And _advertise_ is standard for American English.